# Global Convergence of a simple Alternating Optimization problem

Tags: convergence-divergence, nonlinear-optimization

Let $\bf A$ be a known $M \times M$ matrix with complex-valued entries. The optimization problem is to find which matrices $\bf P$ and $\bf C$ solve

$$ \min | | {\bf A} - {\bf P C }  | |^2,$$

where $\bf C$ is diagonal matrix with complex-valued diagonal entries, ${\bf P}$ is a symmetric matrix (i.e. ${\bf P} = {\bf P}^T$)  with complex-valued entries, and the operator $| | \cdot | |$ denotes the Frobenious norm.

Sadly, the optimization problem is not convex over the entire parameter space $\{ {\bf P} , {\bf C } \}$, but the problem is quadratic if either $ {\bf P}$ or  ${\bf C } $ is fixed. Thus, alternating optimization boils down to solving least squares problems iteratively. With that, we are sure  that the iterations converge as they always decrease the target funtion's value. The problem is proving that this procedure in this setup converges to the global optimum.

Comment: If you are unlucky and start in a local optimum that is not a global optimum, this will not work. But i dont know if such a local optimum exists

Comment: Should $P$ be symmetric or Hermitian?

Comment: $\bf P$ is symmetric, but I guess it would not change the problem it it would be Hermitian.